# Instascan throws no error but does not show video preview

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I'm using the [Instascan](https://github.com/schmich/instascan) library in the latest Chrome version (78.0.3904.108). I have a very basic setup with my Html page (`index.html`):

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js"></script> <!--Qr code scanner-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="user.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><button id="btn_start" onclick="start()">Start</button></p>
    <video id="preview"></video>
</body>
```

And my javascript (`user.js`)

```js
var scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });

function start() {
    Instascan.Camera.getCameras()
        .then((cameras) => {
            scanner.start(cameras[0]);
        })
}
```

When I press start, I can see in the debugger that `scanner.start` is executed with my webcam. No error is shown in the console. However, the video element shows nothing.

How do I make the video element show what my webcam sees?

Answer (score 1):

Please find below working example, you have to paste this code in your workspace to see this working:

```js
 let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });
      scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
        console.log(content);
      });
      Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
        if (cameras.length > 0) {
          scanner.start(cameras[0]);
        } else {
          console.error('No cameras found.');
        }
      }).catch(function (e) {
        console.error(e);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js"></script>
<video id="preview"></video>
```

Comment: What have you changed, and why?

Comment: You probably miss this piece:

if (cameras.length > 0) {
          scanner.start(cameras[0]);
        } else {
          console.error('No cameras found.');
        }

Instascan.Camera.getCameras() returns a camera object, and it is not able to find its camera source

Comment: Also, make sure you grant permission to "Use your camera", when you run this code